# issue with running same code on different laptop using spyder 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, spyder

I am trying to run this on spyder 4

```
import seaborn as sns
anscombe = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
print(anscombe)
```

on my home laptop works fine but on the work one gives me this error.
Can you help?

*

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 7.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
runfile('C:/Users/s023288/Documents/03_ Knowledge/Phyton/pandas_for_everyone-master/seabornTry.py', wdir='C:/Users/s023288/Documents/03_ Knowledge/Phyton/pandas_for_everyone-master')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1414, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 938, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\s023288\Documents\03_ Knowledge\Phyton\pandas_for_everyone-master\seabornTry.py", line 2, in <module>
    anscombe = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 436, in load_dataset
    urlretrieve(full_path, cache_path)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1362, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1321, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

- 

I have also tryed tiwh visual studio code and same result.

Anaconda have been updated/

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to a corporate firewall, speak with your corporate IT administrator. You may have to download the dataset directly from GitHub.